# merging two css files for one project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, bootstrap-4

Essentially, I want to use the [vertical timeline](https://github.com/CodyHouse/vertical-timeline) from CodyHouse in a project hosted on a [Bootstrap template](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-grayscale). When I tried to just copy/paste one into the other, the CodyHouse stuff doesn't show up correctly. Is there an easy solution to doing this?

Comment: Just make sure you include the timeline styles **after** the bootstrap styles. Since Vertical timeline uses its own selector classes, it should work like that.

Comment: @andreas: I've tried that - it implements some, but not all, of the CSS elements. For example, it inherits the h2 style from Bootstrap, but it ignores the date/text in the timeline entirely. It also removes the animation on the vertical timeline.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer, where I tried to reproduce the problem - maybe it can help you?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to reproduce your problem by including the whole *vertical timeline* demo as well as the bootstrap styles.

If you include the bootstrap styles first and then the styles of the timeline, you see in your web inspector, that e.g. for a `<h2>` element the order of applied stylesheets is: *styles.css* than *reset.css* and then the bootstrap CSS:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="cd-nugget-info">
    <a href="https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/">
      <span>
          <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 16;" xml:space="preserve">
            <style type="text/css">
              .cd-nugget-info-arrow{fill:#383838;}
            </style>
            <polygon class="cd-nugget-info-arrow" points="15,7 4.4,7 8.4,3 7,1.6 0.6,8 0.6,8 0.6,8 7,14.4 8.4,13 4.4,9 15,9 "/>
          </svg>
        </span> Article &amp; Download
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-nugget-info -->
  <h1>Responsive Vertical Timeline</h1>
</header>

<section class="cd-timeline js-cd-timeline">
  <div class="cd-timeline__container">
    <div class="cd-timeline__block js-cd-block">
      <div class="cd-timeline__img cd-timeline__img--picture js-cd-img">
        <img src="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__img -->

      <div class="cd-timeline__content js-cd-content">
        <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</p>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-timeline__read-more">Read more</a>
        <span class="cd-timeline__date">Jan 14</span>
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__content -->
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline__block -->

    <div class="cd-timeline__block js-cd-block">
      <div class="cd-timeline__img cd-timeline__img--movie js-cd-img">
        <img src="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-movie.svg" alt="Movie">
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__img -->

      <div class="cd-timeline__content js-cd-content">
        <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde?</p>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-timeline__read-more">Read more</a>
        <span class="cd-timeline__date">Jan 18</span>
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__content -->
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline__block -->

    <div class="cd-timeline__block js-cd-block">
      <div class="cd-timeline__img cd-timeline__img--picture js-cd-img">
        <img src="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__img -->

      <div class="cd-timeline__content js-cd-content">
        <h2>Title of section 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, obcaecati, quisquam id molestias eaque asperiores voluptatibus cupiditate error assumenda delectus odit similique earum voluptatem doloremque dolorem ipsam quae rerum quis. Odit,
          itaque, deserunt corporis vero ipsum nisi eius odio natus ullam provident pariatur temporibus quia eos repellat consequuntur perferendis enim amet quae quasi repudiandae sed quod veniam dolore possimus rem voluptatum eveniet eligendi quis fugiat
          aliquam sunt similique aut adipisci.</p>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-timeline__read-more">Read more</a>
        <span class="cd-timeline__date">Jan 24</span>
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__content -->
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline__block -->

    <div class="cd-timeline__block js-cd-block">
      <div class="cd-timeline__img cd-timeline__img--location js-cd-img">
        <img src="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-location.svg" alt="Location">
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__img -->

      <div class="cd-timeline__content js-cd-content">
        <h2>Title of section 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</p>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-timeline__read-more">Read more</a>
        <span class="cd-timeline__date">Feb 14</span>
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__content -->
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline__block -->

    <div class="cd-timeline__block js-cd-block">
      <div class="cd-timeline__img cd-timeline__img--location js-cd-img">
        <img src="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-location.svg" alt="Location">
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__img -->

      <div class="cd-timeline__content js-cd-content">
        <h2>Title of section 5</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum.</p>
        <a href="#0" class="cd-timeline__read-more">Read more</a>
        <span class="cd-timeline__date">Feb 18</span>
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__content -->
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline__block -->

    <div class="cd-timeline__block js-cd-block">
      <div class="cd-timeline__img cd-timeline__img--movie js-cd-img">
        <img src="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/img/cd-icon-movie.svg" alt="Movie">
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__img -->

      <div class="cd-timeline__content js-cd-content">
        <h2>Final Section</h2>
        <p>This is the content of the last section</p>
        <span class="cd-timeline__date">Feb 26</span>
      </div>
      <!-- cd-timeline__content -->
    </div>
    <!-- cd-timeline__block -->
  </div>
</section>
<!-- cd-timeline -->

<script src="https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes...essentially, it messes with the h2 element and doesn't show any of the p text for the timeline.

Comment: Well you have to provide your code or at least an url of your attempt... otherwise it will be difficult to help.